# Can data size be less than index size in sql database?

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2014, partitioning

Can the indexes on a SQL Server table consume more disk space than the table itself?

I have gone through several articles and studied this and a few expert recommended table partitioning, for example, [this MSDN forums question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a942b4b6-095e-43b4-8510-85438074c75b/what-to-do-if-index-size-larger-than-data-size?forum=sqldatabaseengine)

why can and index be of greater size than the actual data?

How can I reduce index size?

How can I identify unnecessary indexes in this context?

Comment: I've read this a few times now, and I'm still not sure what your question is. Where does partitioning come in? Who recommended it for what? Can you update it to be really clear what information you're looking for?

Comment: @DBOn - "script" the table and it's indexes and add those definitions to your question.   Then add details about the exact problem you are having.  Referencing some question someone else has about a problem tells us nothing about what you need to fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A completely valid table setup might be:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.A
(
    a int NOT NULL
    , b varchar(30) NOT NULL
    , c varchar(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX A_01 ON dbo.A (a, b);
CREATE INDEX A_02 ON dbo.A (a, c);
CREATE INDEX A_03 ON dbo.A (a, c, b);
```

Pretty clearly, the total space used by the indexes will be more than the space used by the table itself.

There are many reasons why the total amount of index space might be higher than that used by the table itself.  Several that immediately come to mind:

- Carelessly chosen index strategy where we "index everything".
- Implementation of every single index recommended by the Database Engine Tuning Advisor
- Favoring query speed for many combinations of queries on a primarily read-only workload, such as a data warehouse.

If you provide the table definition in your question along with all existing indexes, in T-SQL `CREATE TABLE` statements, we may be able to suggest improvements.

Answer (score 2):

A single non clustered index could theoretically be larger than your data size too, since the clustered key is included in the non clustered index as a pointer to the actual row.

So let's say you have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table
(
    a char(30) NOT NULL
    , b char(30) NOT NULL
    , c char(30) NOT NULL
);
```

With a clustered index on a and b, and then create a nonclustered index on b and c the nonclustered index will contain the following column values

```
+------------------+---------------------+
|   index columns  |  bookmark           |
+------------------+---------------------+
|  b     |  c      |  a       |   b      |
+------------------+---------------------+
```

Read [this post by Kalen](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2008/03/16/nonclustered-index-keys.aspx) for an introduction.

If your clustered key isn't unique SQL will even add a 4 bit [uniquifier](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2082/understanding-and-examining-the-uniquifier-in-sql-server/) to the index.